# PHP building directory structure image and css errors

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, frameworks, directory-structure

Sorry If this is basic but its really holding back my learning of correctly building a directory structure and I just cant figure out how to fix the problem.

Consider the following structure:

[image]

**My Problem**

Whenever I create a file in the directory other than src my images and css paths gets messed up i.e its not linked correctly and will get broken.

I guess this is because im using absolute paths for my images...?

**Example**

An image path in the `checkout.php` file will look like this:

`<img src=../resources/imgs/example.png />`

however lets say I want images inside a file called `header.php` displayed site wide (and / or any site wide image and / or css files) Whenever I enter a directory inside the SRC directory like src->users my image and css paths will get broken when I include the views (like `header.php`) into new script within the users directory... src->users

Im sure this is a common problem and Ive searched but Im not really sure how to fix / tackle this problem.

Hope the question makes sense any advise appreciated.

Comment: you have to have the path set to the page it is called.  though your page may be in another dir and to get the image to show you use ../ if the page that is calling the include is above the dir the ../ isnt needed. Sounds like a path problem

Comment: @Jonny would you mind giving a simple example...?Please!

Comment: @Marilee you deleted your question before I could answer it. Don't you need help with the array question posted about 30 min ago?